# SecurityException in my Applet

Tags: java, applet, digital-certificate

I'm not good with Java but when I run my Applet in a simple HTML page, occurs the following error

> SecurityException: Trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource
>   from file : C:/Users/lucas/teste.jar

**Edited: policy tool**

I follow the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) but in the step 7, i got the following error

[image]

Translated:

> Could not open file policy C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\raystore:
>   sun.security.provider.PolicyParser$ParsingException line 1: expected
>   [;] found[pípí]

Comment: Show the complete line you used to sign the jar with jarsigner.  If the path has spaces you may want to add "" around it.

Comment: jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore teste.jar me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets run in a sandbox with limited permissions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

You can sign your Applet as detailed below if you want to override these default permissions.

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

Comment: When I create the policy file, I can't load him. Error: Found (some strange caracteres) Expect(;)

Comment: Digital signing means the policy file is not needed.  Don't waste more time with policy files.

Answer (score 0):

jarsigner is in JDK, not in JRE. Check you have that in your path.

Alternatively write all the command path e.g. %PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\jarsigner.exe

Comment: well, what is myKeyStore ? I found this code on internet but I don't understand... jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore teste.jar me